How to select CSS attribute selector?
We can use attribute selector like that td[colspan]. But I need to use selecting "not colspan". Can you help me?
I tried td[not:colspan] but it is not working. I tried in FrameworkJS but it is not working.
How to select CSS attribute selector?

There is no direct :not selector in CSS for attributes such as colspan. However, you can use the :not() pseudo-class in conjunction with an attribute selector to achieve the effect you want.

You can use td:not([colspan]) selector in your code.

@AyhanYüce No need for comments that say "thank you"; instead, follow the guidance in the help center on what to do when someone answers your question

You were almost there.
td:not([colspan]) 



td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td:not([colspan]) {
  background: lightblue;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>



